# python list appending is not working

Tags: python

I have something similar to:

```
>>> S=list()
>>> T=[1,2,3]
>>> for t in T:
...     print(S.append(t))
```

The output I am getting is:

```
...
None
None
None
```

I expect S contains t. Why this is not working with me ?

Answer (score 19):

[`list.append()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) does not return anything. Because it does not return anything, it default to `None` (that is why when you try print the values, you get `None`).

It simply appends the item to the given list in place. Observe:

```
>>> S = list()
>>> T = [1,2,3]
>>> for t in T:
...     S.append(t)
>>> print(S)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Another example:

```
>>> A = []
>>> for i in [1, 2, 3]:
...     A.append(i) # Append the value to a list
...     print(A) # Printing the list after appending an item to it
... 
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

. append() is a list method, that does not return a value it alters the list.  For example .index() or .count() methods return object values, while .append() alters the object. For example:

```
T = [1, 2, 3]
T.append(4)
print(T)
```

Result:
[1, 2, 3, 4]

We can use .append() to change the list S  and add elements from the list T. Lists S, and T are two separate objects with two different addresses in the memory. With the function id() you can check that.

```
T = [1, 2, 3]
print(id(T))

S = list()
print(S)
print(id(S))

for t in T:
   S.append(t)
print(S)
print(id(S))
```

Result:

```
2476978999688
[]
2476978081224
[1, 2, 3]
2476978081224
```

If you want to use only two different names (S and T)  for the same list, we can write:

```
print(T)
print(id(T))
S = T 
print(S)
print(id(S))
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3]
2476978999688
[1, 2, 3]
2476978999688
```